# Javascript biggest numeric value (add or subtract value)

Tags: javascript, numbers

Why do javascript return a `true` value if I check the following equation:

```
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE === (Number.MAX_VALUE - 1)); // -> true
```

It doesn't matter if I add or subtract a certain value of the max value. Even a big number like `100000` will return `true`.

```
console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE === (Number.MAX_VALUE - 100000)); // -> true
```

I would appreciate any answer, thank you very much.

Comment: https://www.wikitechy.com/tutorials/javascript/what-is-javascripts-highest-integer-value-that-a-number-can-go-to-without-losing-precision

Comment: I've already read this article, but the main question was **why** ? Mathematically, the statement is totally wrong, why do Javascript have such a strange behavior?